# ManyToMany in Play Framework on a same entity

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework-2.0, entity-relationship, hibernate-annotations

I've googled a lot since two days now and I can't find the same problem like the one I'm currently facing regarding hibernate notation.
I want to represent a tree hierarchy based on items. Each item may have zero or more parent items and may have zero or more child items.

My current items class is defined as follow:

```
@Entity
public class Items extends Model {
    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @...
    public List<Items> parents;

    public String name;
}
```

Of course, I would like to have the hierarchy built when I do things like:

```
item1.parents.add (item2);
item2.parents.add (item3);
```

I assume that some kind of bridge table (for items & parents relationships) will be automatically built in SQL database.

I would like to have a solution without adding a child field in Items class.

What should I add in @... in my above example please ?

Thx

Comment: add  @ManyToMany , on doing this play will create a table having items_id and parentItems_id

Comment: I assume you mean `Ebean` by extending `Model`

Comment: Mean "extends play.db.ebean.Model"

Answer (score 1):

That should do the trick

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "items_parents", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "items_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"))
public List<Items> parents = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parents")
public List<Items> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

It creates join table like:

```
create table items_parents (
    items_id              integer not null,
    parent_id             integer not null,
    constraint pk_items_parents primary key (items_id, parent_id)
);
```

Notabene models should use singular form as name i.e. `Item` not `Items`

Edit:

To save ManyToMany relations, you need of course save the item you are adding, otherwise it won't have an `id`, sample:

```
Items parent = new Items();
parent.save(); // <- here

Items child = new Items();
child.parents.add(parent);
child.save();
```

Comment: Thx for the answer...I've tried this but doing a simple scenario: like creating some items and adding son and parent relations causes exception with message like "ManyToMany bean Item@2f336ad4 does not have an Id value" when saving the whole tree,any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: I was a bit fast...it works perfectly for writing..I still have an issue when reading since parents or children field seems empty...why ?